# Arrow function in class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

Code 1:

```
class X1 {
  x = 1;
  get = () => this;
}
a = new X1();
console.log(a.get());
```

Code 2:

```
var X1={
    x:1,
    get:()=>this
}
console.log(X1.get())
```

I don't know why result of code 1 is X1 but code 2 is Window.
Hope guys can help me!!

Answer (score 5):

Class fields are syntax sugar for assigning in the constructor. Code 1 is equivalent to:

```
class X1 {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 1;
    this.get = () => this;
  }
}
```

Inside the constructor, `this` refers to the instance being created - the `a`. Arrow functions inherit `this` from their outer scope. So `this.get = () => this;` results in the returned `this` being the same as the `this` in the outer scope - the instance, or the `a`.

In Code 2, the outer scope is the *top level*. `this` on the top level is either the global object (in a browser, that's `window`), or `undefined`. So, the arrow function `get` which returns `this` returns the `this` on the top level - in sloppy mode in a browser, that's the window.